# Libraries in dotnet core 2.0 get FileNotFound exception

Tags: c#, shared-libraries, .net-core

We have a system that relies heavily on "Adapters" that implement a simple interface for doing unique processing.  Normally, we dynamically load these by assembly name, but in this case we simply want to load them as "Libraries" from within our solution.  In dotnet Core 2.0, this seems to be broken.  I am including a small sample that exhibits this problem.  Perhaps my design is flawed, or something has changed.  This same pattern is working well for us in dotnet Framework (prior to Core).

I am including an example and a screen shot of what my sample project looks like, but this is the jist of it.

[image: Solution Folder Layout]

I have a dotnet core 2.0 "library" called ExternalAdapter.

```
public class TheAdapter : TestExternalInterface.Interfaces.ISomeExternalAdapter
{
    public string GetSomeValue(string valueType)
    {
        switch (valueType)
        {
            case "Red":
            case "red":
                return "Your color is red";
            case "Blue":
            case "blue":
                return "Your color is blue";

            default:
                return "Unknown Value Type";
        }
    }

    public List<string> GetSomeValues(string valueType)
    {
        switch (valueType)
        {
            case "Color":
            case "color":
                return new List<string> { "Red", "Blue" };
            case "Flavor":
            case "flavor":
                return new List<string> { "Sweet", "Savory" };

            default:
                return new List<string> { "Color", "Flavor" };
        }
    }
}
```

It has a class in it named TheAdapter that implements the ISomeExternalAdapter interface.

I have a dotnet core 2.0 "console app" that instantiates a new `ExternalAdapter.TheAdapter()` as the `ISomeExternalAdapter` interface.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("About to load external adapter...Press <ENTER> to continue.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            LoadAndTestExternalAdapter();            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void LoadAndTestExternalAdapter()
    {
        Interfaces.ISomeExternalAdapter adapter = new ExternalAdapter.TheAdapter() as Interfaces.ISomeExternalAdapter;
        Console.WriteLine(adapter.GetSomeValue("red"));
        Console.WriteLine(adapter.GetSomeValues("flavor"));
    }
}
```

This fails with a System.IO.FileNotFoundException:

> Could not load file or assembly 'ExternalAdapter, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Yet when I look in my \bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0 folder of the main program, the ExternalAdapter.dll is found.

If I do a clean / rebuild, it dutifully puts it there as well, so I am pretty sure the file should be found.

Is this a bug in 2.0? or do we need to load "Interfaced" adapters a different way?

Our eventual project has dozens of "adapters" that will be loaded via their interface depending on the type of processing we need to do at our server, but this small example points out the problem we are having in our main app.
Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved by moving the "Interface Definition" to its own library and including that library as a reference in both my ExternalAdapter project and my TestExternalInterface project.  Either that, an update to 2.0 has fixed it - I am not sure.  But after a month I have this working.  A screen shot of the new project layout is as follows:

[image: New Project Layout]